# My cross val score is very low but I have a high accuracy score (Class weights used as well)

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a KerasClassifier with the following model:

```
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=2561 ,activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=50, batch_size=30, verbose=1,validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, class_weight=weights)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

results = cross_val_score(estimator, X_selected, Y, cv=kfold)
print("Baseline: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

When I initially started testing I had problems saw that the accuracy came out very high but the evaluation came out very low (around 50%). I have 6 classes:

AD: 1021
NC: 288
MCI: 229
DLB: 169
VaD: 91
NPH: 84

When I created a confusion matrix from the model I noticed that it was clearly mistaking a majority of the classes for AD since it was the majority:

[image: Confusion matrix]

There is certainly some class imbalance so I used the information found in this [article](https://github.com/christianversloot/machine-learning-articles/blob/main/working-with-imbalanced-datasets-with-tensorflow-and-keras.md) and applied weights to the model:

`{0: 0.30721514854717596, 1: 1.856015779092702, 2: 1.3697234352256187, 3: 1.0891203703703705, 4: 3.734126984126984, 5: 3.446886446886447}`

However, even with these changes I am still getting high training accuracy but low evaluation and  cross val score accuracy.

Comment: I've honestly rarely found it super helpful to use weights during training. Have you checked what the validation set's label distribution is like? If it's similar in proportion to your training set then the performance should be roughly similar. Try starting with a smaller learning rate and going up from there.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: That would be helpful to know how you optimize the hyperparameters of your model... Have you looked at metrics other than accuracy, like AUC?